# How to end .empty()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

i have an array(allArr) of arrays on a function,first time array from position 0 from allArr is taken with image from position 0 from another array with images (named image) 'cause of document.ready then by clicking on a button (id="nextimageandshuffle") arrays from allArr and images from image array reach fifth.My problem is that everytime i click on next button i must clear with empty() the div(id="array") where arrays from allArr are added with append() but i cant stop it after 5th array so the 5th image (from image array) remains there but 5th array (from allArr) its deleted...

Heres my code :

```
var allArr;
var contor = 0;
var i = 0;

$(document).ready( function() { 

    var arr = new Array("images/alfabet/w.png", "images/alfabet/f.png", "images/alfabet/v.png", "images/alfabet/a.png", "images/alfabet/b.png", "images/alfabet/p.png", "images/alfabet/o.png", "images/alfabet/r.png");
    var baiat = new Array("images/alfabet/p.png", "images/alfabet/b.png", "images/alfabet/a.png", "images/alfabet/aa.png", "images/alfabet/i.png","images/alfabet/a.png", "images/alfabet/t.png");
    var colac = new Array("images/alfabet/g.png", "images/alfabet/c.png", "images/alfabet/u.png", "images/alfabet/o.png", "images/alfabet/l.png", "images/alfabet/a.png", "images/alfabet/c.png");
    var slapi = new Array("images/alfabet/s.png", "images/alfabet/ss.png", "images/alfabet/l.png", "images/alfabet/a.png", "images/alfabet/b.png", "images/alfabet/p.png", "images/alfabet/i.png", "images/alfabet/i.png");
    var umbrela = new Array("images/alfabet/u.png", "images/alfabet/n.png", "images/alfabet/m.png", "images/alfabet/p.png", "images/alfabet/b.png", "images/alfabet/r.png", "images/alfabet/e.png", "images/alfabet/l.png", "images/alfabet/a.png");
    allArr = new Array(arr, baiat, colac, slapi, umbrela);
    for(i=0; i<allArr[0].length; i++) 
    {
        var img = new Image();
                    img.src = allArr[0][i];
            $('#array').append(img);

        }
});

var image = new Array("images/baiat.png", "images/colac.png" , "images/slapi.png" , "images/umbrela.png");

var imgNumber=0; 

var numberOfImg = image.length;

function nextImage(){
  if(imgNumber < numberOfImg){
    imgNumber++;
    }
  document.slideImage.src = image[imgNumber-1];

   contor++; 

   $("#array").empty();


   for(i = 0; i<allArr[contor].length; i++) 
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = allArr[contor][i];
        $('#array').append(img);

    }


 }

if(document.images){

   var image1 = new Image();
   image1.src = "images/vapor.png";
   var image2 = new Image();
   image2.src = "images/baiat.png";
   var image3 = new Image();
   image3.src = "images/colac.png";
   var image4 = new Image();
   image4.src = "images/slapi.png";
   var image5 = new Image();
   image5.src = "images/umbrela.png";

   }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/vapor.png" name="slideImage" class='secondcanvas' width='450' height='300' alt="">
       <div id="array" class='thirdcanvas'></div>  
<a href="#" onClick="nextImage()"><img id="nextimageandshuffle" src="images/nextBtn.png" title="Continuare" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to do, but I think I got it...

You will need to determine if you are on the last image or not, because if your not you still want to empty the element. Compared the current images src to the string in allArr[4][4] and if they match, don't do the .empty().  So instead of just:

```
$("#array").empty();
```

You will want to replace it with something like:

```
if(img.src == allArr[4][4]){
    return;
}else{
    $("#array").empty();
}
```

Comment: Cool,i forgot to add else when i was thinking to use if,but mine and your if doesnt work...we must equal last position image from image array with last array named umbrela from allArr...if we click next untill umbrela array,stop the .empty() else do .empty()

Comment: Ah, I see. When I originally read it I thought you were pulling the images in on the fly on each click of "next". If they are all being populated when the document is loaded, you are right in needing to grab the position. Glad I could help!

Comment: I figurate out how to do it,i made a condition for contor to end after 4th array so,from now on even if i click next..can't go after 4th array :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understood what your problem is. However if you want to keep the last image in your `div` tag after calling `empty()`, you just have to append it again :

```
$("#array").empty();
var lastImage = new Image();
lastImage.src = allArr[4][4];
$("#array").append(lastImage);
```

Please tell me if this helps or not.

Comment: It does something but not what i need :(thx for ur answer anyway :D @Ant answered with if and it looks interesting,i've been thinking like that but without else